# NodeJS, doesn't close mysql connection

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I actually use this [MYSQL Client](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) and when I close a connection is actually never closes , so I can see in the status.

```
router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {

    var conn = mysql.createConnection(config);

    conn.connect();

    conn.query('select  * from invoices ', function (err, result) {

        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        res.status(200).json({result: result});
        conn.end();// || conn.destroy();
    });

});
```

[image: Connections]

Answer (score 4):

Move `conn.end()` out of the query callback - as described in [node-mysql's documentation](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#introduction):

> Every method you invoke on a connection is queued and executed in sequence.
>
> Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Comment: Hi, I try that and it didn't work , also I try with the method `conn.destroy()` and didn't work.

Comment: Having the same issue,  end() and destroy() do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use pool.

Check [this link](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#pooling-connections).

> Connections can be pooled to ease sharing a single connection, or
>   managing multiple connections.
>
> When you are done with a connection, just call connection.release()
>   and the connection will return to the pool, ready to be used again by
>   someone else.

```
pool.end(function (err) {
  // all connections in the pool have ended
});
```