# Can't close mysql connection with NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

this is really annoying I just can't close my mysql connection. Here is my code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function getConnection(){
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host     : credentials.db.host,  //'eu-cdbr-azure-north-e.cloudapp.net',
        user     : credentials.db.user,     //'b1a8cac71bbac61',
        password : credentials.db.password,     //'be2de8334',
        database : credentials.db.database     //'bcd290081'
    });
}

function runMySQLQuery(qry, callback){
    var conn = getConnection();
    conn.connect();
    conn.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err){
            // db err
            callback(Error.sql_query, null);
        } else{
            // check result
            if(typeof rows == 'object'){
                callback(Error.no_errors, rows);
            }else{
                // wrong return from db
                callback(Error.sql_query, null);
            }
        }

    });
    //conn.destroy();
    conn.end(function(err) {
        // The connection is terminated now 
        console.log('connection ended');
    });
}

var qry = "SELECT id, hash, last_login FROM acsm_b962fe317b5d30e.orium_chatbot_customers " +
            "WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "';"
//console.log('qry', qry);
runMySQLQuery(qry, callback);
```

So, I'm receiving the data I want, but the connection keeps open, I tried both the destroy and end methods (with and without a callback function) and my program just do not end. It takes about a minute to it finally ends, and then it calls the end's callback function.

Really annoying, I also saw another [stackoverflow doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35438083/nodejs-doesnt-close-mysql-connection) about this with not much success too.

It is very important for me to close the connection because I want to deploy my code on AWS Lambda, and I can't afford this to take so long.

Comment: when was the time you want it to close?

Comment: After my query was executes, you see I call callback and then conn.end

Comment: try connection.on('error', function(error) { console.log(error); });

Comment: I added this code before conn.end, nothing new is printed.

Answer (score 1):

> use this code to mysql connection release

```
1) conn.release();

2) conn.destroy();
```

Comment: Hey man, unfortunatelly this did not work, realease it's not a method available because it's not a pool, and I tried destroy before, it still does not close the connection :(

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution on my own. It was really a bad guess, but it worked. I'm not sure if node-mysql is supposed to work like this, but I only had to add some code to the function runMySQLQuery:

```
function runMySQLQuery(qry, callback){
    var conn = getConnection();
    conn.connect();
    conn.query(qry, function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            return conn.rollback(function() {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
                throw Error.sql_query;
            });
        }  
        conn.commit(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return conn.rollback(function() {
                    throw Error.sql_commit;
                });
            }
            conn.destroy();
            callback(Error.no_errors, rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Turns out that calling destroy after calling commit actually ended the connection. Again, calling only destroy or end did not workefor me.

Comment: connect() is async, right?   does query wait for the connection before executing?